# Python tornado - How to use Post method to same page

Tags: python, http-post, tornado

I am following the github demo from the repo located at https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/tree/master/demos/chat but I cannot figure out how to Post in the index.html without redirect or render in a different html page. Is the redirection controlled by the python script or the js dile?

Comment: Create a method called `post` in the handler class. The `get` method handles the GET requests. `post` method will handle POST requests. Here's a list of methods supported by tornado: https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.get

Comment: @xyres I would like to have a button with the post method that can redirect to the same index.html like it is done in the demo but I dont know how do they keep the data.

Comment: That's done using JS. This technique is called AJAX. Here's a resource to learn more: https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/